# Iterating a conversion of a string to a float in a scripting file when parsing an old file

Tags: python

I am using a new script (a) to extract information from an old script (b) to create a new file (c). I am looking for an equal sign in the old script (b) and want to modify the modification script (a) to make it automated.

The string is
lev1tolev2 'from=e119-b3331l1 mappars="simp:180" targ=enceladus.bi.def.3 km=0.6 lat=(-71.5,90) lon=(220,360)'
It is written in python 3.

The current output is fixed at
cam2map from=e119-b3331l1 to=rsmap-x map=enc.Ink.map pixres=mpp defaultrange=MAP res=300 minlat=-71.5 maxlat=90 minlon=220 maxlon=360

Currently, I have the code able to export a string of 0.6 for all of the iterations of lev1tolev2, but each one of these is going to be different.

```
    cam2map = Call("cam2map")
    cam2map.kwargs["from"] = old_lev1tolev2.kwargs["from"]
    cam2map.kwargs["to"] = "rsmap-x"
    cam2map.kwargs["map"] = "enc.Ink.map"
    cam2map.kwargs["pixres"] = "mpp"
    cam2map.kwargs["defaultrange"] = "MAP"
    **cam2map.kwargs["res"] = float((old_lev1tolev2.kwargs["km"]))**
    cam2map.kwargs["minlat"] = lat[0]
    cam2map.kwargs["maxlat"] = lat[1]
    cam2map.kwargs["minlon"] = lon[0]
    cam2map.kwargs["maxlon"] = lon[1]
```

I have two questions, why is this not converting the string to a float? And, why is this not iterating over all of the lev1tolev2 commands as everything else in the code does?

The full code is available here.

https://codeshare.io/G6drmk

Comment: your `(a)`s and `(b)`s seem inconsistent. Please check your question again. Is `(a)` the *new* script or the *old* script?

Comment: Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't seem to clear to me, but from you syntax here :

`**cam2map.kwargs["res"] = float((old_lev1tolev2.kwargs["km"]))**`

I'd bet that cam2map.kwargs["res"] is a dict, and you thought that it would convert every values in the dict, using the ** syntax. The float built-in should then be called in a loop over the elements of the dict, or possible a list-comprehension as here :

```
cam2map.kwargs["res"] = dict()
for key, value in old_lev1tolev2.kwars["res"].items():
    cam2map.kwargs["res"][key] = float(value)
```

Edit : 
Ok so,  it seems you took the string 'from=e119-b3331l1 mappars="simp:180" targ=enceladus.bi.def.3 km=0.6 lat=(-71.5,90) lon=(220,360)' 
And then thought that calling youstring.kwargs would give you a dict, but it won't, you can probably parse it to a dict first, using some lib, or,  you use mystring.split('=') and then work your way to a dict first, like that:

```
output = dict()
for one_bit in lev_1_lev2.split(' '):
    key, value = one_bit.split('=')
    output[key] = value
```

Comment: the ** was just to signify that this was the line of interest. I have tried to set that up as a dictionary somewhere else with this command.

km = parse_tuple_3x(old_lev1tolev2.kwargs["km"])

Comment: i've edited it, tell me if i got you right ^^, if not, could you please print the definition of old_lev1tolev2 here ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred at a different location in the code.
def escape_kw_value(value):

```
if not isinstance(value, str):
    return value
elif (value.startswith(('"', "'")) and value.endswith(('"', "'"))):
    return value

# TODO escape the quote with \" or \'
#if value.startswith(('"', "'")) or value.endswith(('"', "'")):
#    return value

if " " in value:
    value = '"{}"'.format(value)
return value
```